# Can iBooks be read without a data connection?

Tags: iphone, books, cellular-data

If I am out of my service area can I still read a book in iBooks on my iPhone?  If not, is it possible to download part of the book and read it while I am out of the area?

Comment: I used iBooks on my iPod touch when not on WiFi all the time before I got an iPhone.

Comment: Has something given you the impression that the books are not downloaded fully to each device?

Comment: I know its old topic, but this situation exists now.
"Has something given you the impression that the books are not downloaded fully to each device?" Since an update, it drags ass opening iBooks even to a book I've been reading, and the little wheel is grinding away. So once, I hit airplane mode, and of course I was prompted to hit "unplane mode". It still opens anyway, but only after crapping on my data minutes?
Full disclosure: I put off updating so long that I immediately have another update available. I shall have to see if my mileage varies

Answer (score 12):

Yes, iBooks can function normally while not connected to the internet. As long as you have the book(s) present in the iBooks app before you get out of coverage you will be fine.

If you are out of your coverage area and connect to another network, or roaming, you might have additional expenses for using another network.

Answer (score 1):

1. Transfer the books from Mac to iPad/iPhone via iCloud.
2. Use Files app to access the books from iPad/iPhone. Open them in iBooks and download them from cloud while connected to internet.
3. Once it's done, go to iCloud location in Files app, select all the books and move to the "On my iPad/iPhone" location (for eg., Keynote folder). Turn off internet and see if you can open the books from "On my iPad/iPhone" location.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can I have an iPhone 5s and I tried it without any data services when I was at my brothers baseball game it does work